# How can I minimise repeated bindings when pivoting component type?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a series of data objects which all inherit from the same base class.

```ts
export interface DataObjectBase {
    type: string;
    /* ... other shared fields */
}

export interface DataObjectA extends DataObjectBase { /* ... */ }
export interface DataObjectB extends DataObjectBase { /* ... */ }
export interface DataObjectC extends DataObjectBase { /* ... */ }
```

The object type is identified by the value of the `'type'` property present on every object. I can safely cast an object to `DataObjectA` if its `type` property is `"A"`, for example.

For each of these object types, I have a component. The components all inherit from the same base class, and also therefore have shared common `@Input()` and `@Output()` bindings, but also may have some explicit bindings of their own as well.

For example:

```ts
export class MyComponentBase<T extends DataObjectBase> {
    @Input() public data: T;
    @Input() public someValue: string;
    @Input() public someOtherValue: number;
    @Output() public someOtherValueChanged: EventEmitter<number>;
    @Output() public someEvent: EventEmitter<string>;
}

@Component({selector: 'component-a', templateUrl: './component-a.template.html'})
export class MyComponentA extends MyComponentBase<DataObjectA> { /* ... */ }

@Component({selector: 'component-b', templateUrl: './component-b.template.html'})
export class MyComponentB extends MyComponentBase<DataObjectB> { /* ... */ }

@Component({selector: 'component-c', templateUrl: './component-c.template.html'})
export class MyComponentC extends MyComponentBase<DataObjectC> { /* ... */ }
```

Each subclassed component has its own template, and does different things with the internal bindings.

In my host component, I use an `ngSwitch` to swap the component implementations based on the data, however, I'm finding I'm needing to implement a lot of repetitive binding boilerplate:

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="data.type">
    <component-a
        *ngSwitchCase="'A'"
        #object
        [data]="data"
        [someValue]="someValue"
        [(someOtherValue)]="someOtherValue"
        (someEvent)="onSomeEvent($event)"></component-a>
    <component-b
        *ngSwitchCase="'B'"
        #object
        [data]="data"
        [someValue]="someValue"
        [(someOtherValue)]="someOtherValue"
        (someEvent)="onSomeEvent($event)"></component-a>
    <component-c
        *ngSwitchCase="'C'"
        #object
        [data]="data"
        [someValue]="someValue"
        [(someOtherValue)]="someOtherValue"
        (someEvent)="onSomeEvent($event)"></component-a>
</ng-container>
```

I'm hoping to be able to simplify the repeated `#object [data]="data" [someValue]="someValue" [(someOtherValue)]="someOtherValue" (someEvent)="onSomeEvent($event)"` into something like `[sharedBindings]`, so I can do something more like:

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="data.type">
    <component-a *ngSwitchCase="'A'" [sharedBindings]></component-a>
    <component-b *ngSwitchCase="'B'" [sharedBindings]></component-b>
    <component-c *ngSwitchCase="'C'" [sharedBindings] [cSpecificValue]="foo"></component-c>
</ng-container>
```

There are significantly more bindings than this, and I've got around 12 different components and counting. Trying to keep the components as stateless as possible means this is becoming more and more cumbersome. **How can I avoid repeating all of those bindings?**

I've tried creating a directive that uses to `@HostBinding` to bind to the values:

```ts
@Directive({selector: '[sharedBindings]'})
export class SharedBindingsDirective {
    @Input('sharedBindings') public component: MyComponentBase;

    @HostBinding('data')
    public get data(): DataObjectBase {
        return this.component.data;
    }
}
```

however, of course, you don't seem able to bind to `@Input` or `@Output` properties (nor could I imagine a way to also represent `#object` in the host component so that I can access it as a `@ViewChild`).

Is there *any* way I can combine or collapse the repeated bindings while keeping the polymorphic nature of the components themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a switch case in html, I think you can use angular's ComponentFactoryResolver to dynamically create your component. You can also put this logic inside a directive instead of component. You can do another switch cases to bind extra values that is not shared.

[image]

Comment: This seems like a one-time passing of input values (on creation) - not template-handled binding. In the interest of keeping things as atomic as possible, I assume I won't have a template-able way of setting up input/output bindings, getting ViewChildren as their expected type, etc ...? How would I, say, bind `[ngModel]` to one of these components when using this pattern?

Comment: you can bind anything. If your instance has an eventEmitter, an Observer, or a method, all can be assigned/bind through this setup.